# Update react state after a certain interval

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        data : [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,3,1,4,12,2,3,2]
    };

}
componentDidMount(){setInterval(this.updateCanvas(),5000);}

updateCanvas() {
    console.log(this.props.newData);
    let data = this.state.data.slice();
    let length = data.length;
    console.log(length);
    data.push(20);
    this.setState({data:data},()=>{console.log(this.state.data);});
}
```

I am trying to push a new value to the state every 5s, but the state changes immediately. How can I achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 3):

The state changes immediate because you are invoking the callback method you pass to setInterval immediately on this line by adding parenthesis to it:

```
setInterval(this.updateCanvas(),5000);
//---------------------------^
// Adding these to function will invoke it
```

The solution is to pass the reference to the function without the parenthesis (and they're not invoking it immediately)

```
setInterval(this.updateCanvas,5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that bracket from this.updateCanvas().
Ie
setInterval(this.updateCanvas, 5000);}

The first will execute the function immediately whilst the second passes it in as a function for set interval

Answer (score 0):

**Why doesn't it work?**

There are actually two problems:

1. You need to pass a function to `setInterval`. The [`setInterval` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) excepts a function as it's 1st parameter. When you use`setInterval(this.updateCanvas(),5000);`, you pass the returned value of the invoked method `this.updateCanvas()`. Since the method returns nothing (undefined), what you actually get is `window.setInterval(undefined, 5000);`.
2. You have to bind that function to the component instance's `this`. Since the `updateCanvas` method uses `this`, for example `this.setState()`,

**Binding `updateCanvas` to `this` and invoking in `setInterval`:**

- Pass `setInveral` an arrow function, and invoke `updateCanvas` inside:

  ```
  componentDidMount(){
      setInterval(() => this.updateCanvas(),5000);
  }
  ```

**Or**

- Bind the method to the component instance `this`:

  ```
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={
          data : [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,3,1,4,12,2,3,2]
      };

      this.updateCanvas = this.updateCanvas.bind(this); // bind the method to this
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      setInterval(this.updateCanvas,5000);
  }
  ```